# Micrometer Tracing not working with Spring Boot 2.2.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing

I am using the spring boot 2.2.2.Release version.

this is my controller class.

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(HelloController.class);
    @GetMapping(value = "{userId}")
    public String test(@PathVariable("userId") String userId){
        LOGGER.info("user =  {}",userId);
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

this is my pom.xml and in the detail i have added the micrometer tracing library and use the spring boot 2.2.2 version. and also i use the log4j2 library.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>loglama</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>loglama</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
         </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-jul</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-log4j-appender</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.micrometer/micrometer-tracing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.micrometer/micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
                <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

this is the pattern and i added **[%X{traceId},%X{spanId}]**.

```
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS}] [%X{traceId},%X{spanId}] [%p] - %l - %m%n
```

the log output is :

```
[2023-07-11 10:45:49:889] [,] [INFO] - com.example.loglama.controller.HelloController.test(HelloController.java:18) - user =  demo123
```

if you can see the traceId and spaceId are empty.
the company doesn't want to upgrade the spring boot version for that I have to fix this issue with this version.
How can fix this issue ?

Comment: You only added dependencies as there is no auto configuration for Micrometer in this version of Spring Boot you have to manually register all necessary components.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. what do you mean manually register necessary components ?
I didn't find do you have any links,pls ?

Comment: Check what Spring Boot 3 is registering for components in the context to enable micrometer tracing, you will need to replicate that for Spring Boot 2.2.

Comment: sorry, I still didn't understand what is registering for components in the context to enable micrometer tracing. they said that just add the library and use it  in the all tutorial.
am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you think adding some dependencies, write a log line will automagically work? Support for Micrometer was **added in Spring Boot 3**, so if you try it with **Spring Boot 2** this won't automagically work. You will need to setup micrometer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Distributed Tracing and if you are on:

- Spring Boot 2.7.x -> you should use Spring Cloud Sleuth
- Spring Boot 3.x.  -> you should use Micrometer Tracing

(Boot 2.2.x is very old and no longer supported, you should upgrade.)